# I'm missing items when I sublist a list into multiple new lists. How can I sublist without losing data?

Tags: java, list, hashmap

I have a list of 10 items:

```
List<ServiceLineTypeResource> serviceLineList = serviceLineRepository.findAll();
```

Print Output:

```
[Backup, COI, Network, Oracle, SQL_Activities, Storage, Unix/Linux, Virtualization, Windows, #N/A]
```

...that I want to split into three separate lists of each 3 items each, excluding the final item:

```
List<ServiceLineTypeResource> serviceLineListRow1 = serviceLineList.subList(0, min(serviceLineList.size(), 3));
List<ServiceLineTypeResource> serviceLineListRow2 = serviceLineList.subList(4, min(serviceLineList.size(), 7));
List<ServiceLineTypeResource> serviceLineListRow3 = serviceLineList.subList(8, min(serviceLineList.size(), 11));
```

I'm adding each to a HashMap along with another unrelated list:

```
HashMap<String, String> rowHashMap1 = new HashMap<>();
List<String> styleList = new ArrayList<>();
styleList.add("tile-pink");
styleList.add("tile-sqr tile-cyan");
styleList.add("tile-sqr tile-purple");
for (int i = 0; i < serviceLineListRow1.size(); i++) {
    rowHashMap1.put(serviceLineListRow1.get(i).getName(), styleList.get(i));
    System.out.println("Row 1: " + serviceLineListRow1.get(i).getName());
}
```

Output:

```
Row 1: Backup
Row 1: COI
Row 1: Network
Row 2: SQL_Activities
Row 2: Storage
Row 2: Unix/Linux
Row 3: Windows
Row 3: #N/A
```

For some reason it's always skipping the 8th item in the list, `Virtualization` and gives the  last one, `#` instead. I want each of my "row" lists to contain three items, and I don't want the `#` to appear in any of them. What's going on here?

Comment: Just look at your indices. The first sublist [0, 3[ contains indices 0, 1 and 2. The second [4, 7[ contains 4, 5 and 6. So you forgot index 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-

> Returns a view of the portion of this list between the specified fromIndex, inclusive, and toIndex, exclusive.

So if you want the first 9 items you need to do:

```
List<ServiceLineTypeResource> serviceLineListRow1 = serviceLineList.subList(0, min(serviceLineList.size(), 3));
List<ServiceLineTypeResource> serviceLineListRow2 = serviceLineList.subList(3, min(serviceLineList.size(), 6));
List<ServiceLineTypeResource> serviceLineListRow3 = serviceLineList.subList(6, min(serviceLineList.size(), 9));
```

Comment: Looks good but for my last list I had to do this: ``List<ServiceLineTypeResource> serviceLineListRow3 = serviceLineList.subList(6, min(serviceLineList.size() - 1, 9));``

Comment: @santafebound Why? This will only return indices 6 and 7 if your list has size 9, instead of 6, 7 and 8. You've created a new bug, for the exact same reason. What you should do, however, is to avoid creating sublist from 3 to 2 (for example) if your list size is 2, because that makes no sense.

Comment: @JBNizet It should still work for him if his list has 10 items then it would just be `min(9,9)`. But there should be no reason to do it. Unless he can have a list with less then 9 items and always wants to ignore the last member.

Comment: There would really be no point of using min() everywhere if the list is guaranteed to have 10 elements. But well... you never know.

Comment: I have a list of 10 items though. I wanted to create 3 lists of 3 items, and remove the last one.

Comment: @santafebound Then you can just remove all the `min` and just use the numbers 3,6,9. What's `min` by the way? `Math.min` or your own function?

Comment: Lol yeah it is ``Math.min``. I was overthinking something.